# What Database type should I use for a scraped data comes from many websites?

Tags: node.js, mysql, sql, scraping, mongodb

I'm building a REST API using NodeJS storing a scraped data that comes from many websites ( the API I'm building is about selling - buying used cars )

> There's a potential to scale in the future for more products, not just
>   cars!

I searched a lot for a recommendation for what DB should I use SQL or NoSQL ( MySql or MongoDB )

What I get from searching:

1. That MySql slow on writes data ( scraping is about writes ) (
   **Mongo feature** )
2. but the data it has relationships like car => brand => model => user
   ...etc  ( **MySQL Feature** )

Another confusing is the data will not have a schema as can change from site to another ( **Mongo Feature** )

**I'm really frustrated right now? which Database I should use in my situation?**

Answer (score 0):

MySql will never be so "slow" that you will notice it.

I googled for `mysql insert speed`, [this](https://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/) is the first thing I found & it speaks of 1,000 inserts per second.

Do you seriously believe that you will need anything like that kid of performance? You can't scrape 1k pages/sec, owing to internet latency.

Btw, that blog post got it up to 28k inserts/second. Read [this](https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723) if you need more - but you don't.

Stick with the advantages of an RBDMS.